# How to convert a lot of data from binary file to string of ones and zeros fast

Tags: python, string, binaryfiles, converters

I try to convert the data in binary file to string of ones and zeros.
The size of the binary file is about 2MB which right takes a lot of time to convert it all, how can I make it faster

I have tried to cut the process to pieces by converting the bytes to int and from there to string

```
def bytes_to_string(self, xbytes):
    intermediate_result = int.from_bytes(xbytes, byteorder='big')
    return intermediate_result


def dec_to_bin(self,x):
    return int(bin(x)[2:])

##
## bin_code is where the data from the binary file is stored

bin_code = str(self.dec_to_bin(self.bytes_to_string(bin_code)))
```

Comment: `str(int(xbytes, 2))` might help

Comment: I tried using it but it doesn't work, it' return: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2

Comment: i think you need to give example for your xbytes, as little desired input also

Comment: you are right, but it's too long  and it's in hex and i cant print it here

Comment: Is it the hyphen?

Comment: @DarkKnight35 you should mentioned it earlir then, just do `str(int(xbytes,16))`

Comment: @prashantrana ,  still doesn't work, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16 b'\x05MS+\xc4=.*\xf1R\x11\xcfa\x8d|g\xd8\xca\xf2\xbe$\xfa\x90\xb62\xbc\xf8\xd6Rr ...

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?  Your code seems to confuse how numeric values are represented and the values themselves - if you explain what you are trying to do we can help.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution would be:

```
"".join([format(ord(byte), "08b") for byte in bytes])
```

Although, I dont know how fast it is.